Function samplable from the past and Hardy spaces
What I am ultimately looking for is a $L^2$ function $f$ on the real line that can be sampled from the past, i.e. for each $x<0$ there are $L^2$ coefficients $c_n(x)$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$  such that, $$f(x)=\sum_{n\leq 0} c_n(x) f(n).$$
I cannot use the Shanon sampling theorem because I alse need that $f$'s spectrum contains the positive half line.
Here is my analysis so far: such a sampling result seems to be true for functions $f$ which FT $\hat f$ has exponential decay. The problem comes from the requirement that the prediction can be made from samples on negative integers. It can work if I require $f$ to vanish on the whole positive half line, then $\hat f$ is in a Hardy space, but it cannot have exponential decay as $f$ has too many zeros, so my idea would be to only require $f$ to vanish on the positive integers.
So in conclusion it would work if I find $\hat f$ with support on the positive half line and exponential decay which (inverse) Fourier transform $f$ vanishes on the positive integers.

Would you mind being a bit more precise about what you are looking for ? Quite trivially for any fixed function there exist such coefficients. Also, do you mean convergence in norm or almost everywhere ? Do you ask for $c_n(x)$ to be specifically the sync functions or any functions ?

You are right this is not clear, the function $f$ is known but it is applied a random shift that is unknown, I will rewrite the question more clearly. The coefficients can be anything. I have written a convergence for every $x$, but a $L^2$ convergence would do.
